# Amazon Redshift: Case types character varying and numeric cannot be matched

Tags: sql

I am having the below query .. did not have the numeric and varchar in all the lines without the last one. I added all of them now and i still get the error. Not sure where i'm going wrong.. Can someone help?

```
CASE WHEN STR_COORD.correlated =1 THEN str.physical_lattitude :: numeric(12,8) 
     WHEN STR_COORD.correlated != 1 AND str_coord.Source = 'NRS' then str.physical_lattitude :: numeric(12,8) 
     WHEN str_coord.source !='NRS' and STR_COORD.correlated != 1 then  str_coord.source = 'NN' :: varchar
     else str.physical_lattitude end :: numeric(12,8) as store_latitude
```

Comment: What are the data types of the columns?

Comment: That indicates inconsistent table definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
WHEN str_coord.source !='NRS' and STR_COORD.correlated != 1 then  str_coord.source = 'NN' :: varchar
```

To

```
WHEN str_coord.source = 'NN' and STR_COORD.correlated != 1 then 1 :: numeric(12,8)
WHEN str_coord.source !='NRS' and STR_COORD.correlated != 1 then 0 :: numeric(12,8)
```

And remove the final cast `:: numeric(12,8)` after `end` since all values from the case are already that type.

Comment: CASE WHEN STR_COORD.correlated  = 1 THEN str.physical_lattitude 
     WHEN STR_COORD.correlated  != 1 AND str_coord.Source = 'NRS' then str.physical_lattitude 
     WHEN str_coord.source = 'NN' and STR_COORD.correlated != 1 then 1 :: numeric(12,8)
     WHEN str_coord.source !='NRS' and STR_COORD.correlated != 1 then 0 :: numeric(12,8)
     else str.physical_lattitude end  as store_latitude                 Same error..